# No `emacsclient` binary when building from source

Tags: emacsclient, build

I have built Emacs [from source](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs) and, after `make` ends successfully, no `emacsclient` binary is present in the output (`./src`) directory. What is the recommended way to get the `emacsclient` binary in this situation to have it work with the built version?

EDIT:

Info: Ubuntu 16.04, building Emacs 26.3, build settings: `./configure --with-modules CC=clang` (to avoid existing dynamic modules [bug](https://github.com/dzop/emacs-jupyter/issues/22) with gcc).

Comment: Please provide a little more details regarding what operating system and build settings you are using, including, but not limited to the `--prefix=...` (if any):  E.g., on OSX, `--with-ns` will put everything inside an `Emacs.app` inside the `nextstep` folder; and, on Windows, ....; and, on X/X11, ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct. The emacsclient binary is not present in the source src directory. It is however present in the lib-src directory. So do a `make install`, if you have not already done so, to put the emacsclient binary in your build directory, wherever you have chosen that to be.